# What is the Origin of '' 'sup? ''

Tags: etymology, phrases, slang, contractions

Sup is a contraction or aphetic of the older term ''what's up?'', Does anyone know how it has originated?

Comment: ..erm, Wayans family?

Comment: It originated the same way all aphetic forms originate: by loss of an unstressed syllable. There are many similar cases in languages all over the world – there’s not necessarily any ‘reason’ to it. It just happens.

Comment: People talking.

Comment: People talking lazily.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet That's just a way of waving the question away as if it didn't merit an answer whilst answering in the comments!

Answer (score 2):

**what’s up?** phr.  [Green's Dictionary of Slang](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/yrrtnli) The usages and dates also here. 
also **’sup?** wassup? whassup? wha’s up? what up? whazzap? wuzzup? ’zup?

From **what's up'**:

> 1855  [UK]    W. Phillips Wild Tribes of London 104: Hilloh, Tom! **what’s
>   up**, that you are obleeged to patch up your crab-shells? [...] Mr.
>   Bradley [...] replies that ‘nuffin’s up’, but that times is bad.

to,

> 1915  [UK]    T. Burke Nights in Town 305: Some cried ‘**Whassup?**’.

to,

**s'up?**  [Green's Dictionary of Slang](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/yrrtnli)

> used as a greeting US A slurred “what’s up?”. — Connie Eble (Editor),
>   UNC-CH Campus Slang, p. 6, Fall 1981

this term of greeting has progressed from standard grammar to the shortened lazy colloquial.

Comment: _OED_ has _wassup_ also and the earliest citation is from 1902: "A. Morrison _Hole in Wall_ 31     Marr, ducking and lolling over the table, here looked up and said: ‘Wassup? Fiddler won' go? Gi'm twopence an' kick'm downstairs.’"

Comment: yes, the OED has many.  I included just 3 in big jumps of time.